# Python File Not Found whilst both python and excel file in the same folder. Why?

Tags: python

I watched the youtube from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HU0re8UJViM and stuck at File Not Found problem. I checked other posts such as [Import Excel file Python Pandas (File not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289221/import-excel-file-python-pandas-file-not-found) and still not able to find any solutions.

I'm using Visual Studio Code on mac system to run python.

The full code from the youtube is as below with modified filename:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file_path = 'Test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

print(df.head(2))
```

Attached is a screenshot as a proof that both python and excel are in the same folder.

[image]

The full path to the folder is /Users/User/M/M1/DS project

I have tried these filenames, Test, Test.xlsx, Test.xlsx.xlsx but doesn't seem to help.

I believe it should be a simple fix but I just can't find the solution after reading so many relevant posts. Can someone help please? Thanking in advance.

Comment: Try giving different names for the `.py` and `.xlsx` files.

Comment: You're probably not running it from the directory you think you are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try and use the full file path and see if the issue persists. In my experience VS code runs the python script in a different location than where it is saved. So it might be looking for the file in a different directory than where it is saved.

Comment: Superb. It works and I also found the issue lies with one of my folder name where it doesn't recognise Name's. Changing to Name fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the  python virtualenv model for your projects. This provides an environment for the program to understand the connection of your files.

1. Create a directory and put your files in it.
2. Open terminal and install virtualenv :

> `pip install virtualenv`

3. In terminal, Get in the project directory and create new venv:

> `python -m virtualenv venv`

4. Now you have to active you venv:

> `source venv/bin/activate`

now start runnig your project.

for deactivate directory just type:

> `deactivate`